# chat room anonymous identification

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, chat

I am trying to make a random chat with ASP.NET and ajax/jquery. When user enters the chat room, I need a way to identify the user and give him a unique id with which I will record his words in my database. Do I need to use session, cookie or something else? What would be the best way to implement the random chat??

Comment: I'm not an ASP programmer but I think you should use the session_id for that

Comment: Thanks, Glide. I wonder if using the session ID is a norm for this kind of website.

Comment: That's seems the most logical for me

Comment: Its worth checking this demo random chat app for anonymous chat http://talkwithstranger.com/free-chat-rooms/random-chat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sessions:**

```
- Will expire if the user are idle for some time in the chat
- Will be terminated when the browser closes, by the server.
+ Cannot be changed by the user
```

**Cookies**

```
+ Will not expire
+ Will not be terminated on browser close, so the system can identify the user to be the same the next time
- Can be changed by the user
```

The absolute best way to identify the user will be a combination of a database (MySQL / Oracle / MSSQL) and cookies.

- Put a random unique keystring in the cookie to identify an input in the database.
- Use the input in the database to withhold all the information on the user.

Comment: No problem, that's what we are here for! :)

Comment: Sessions are configurable, you can change the timeout (there usualy are timeouts on chats). And remember it's an anonymous chat.

Comment: The absolute best chats lets you stay logged in, but setting your status as idle. And not using AJAX but Comet Pooling to send the chat to the user instead of the user requesting the chat from the server :) And yes, you can change the timeout of the session, but this really depends on how much access you have to the web server. If it is a shared server-host, they normally have a limit on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a `session_id`